# Shopify Customize dynamic checkout buttons to products with third party Bank

Tags: button, dynamic, shopify, product, checkout

Currently, I have an e-book I want to sell via Shopify, I already have added the dynamic buttons, but one of them is a third party Bank that I'm using to process the payment.

The issue is, I don't know if is possible to integrate a third-party functionality (external bank), when after the payment has been done, a download link is sent via email, so the person who just purchased the book can donwload it.

Anybody know the answer to this or now a possible integration solution with a third-party?

Thank you so much.

I already have added the dynamic button, but I can't find a way to customize the liquid code, so when after the payment is done, it redirects and the donwload link is sent via email.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit your

**admin > settings > payment providers > choose thrid party providers**

**https://{{yourstorename}}.myshopify.com/admin/settings/payments/third-party-providers**

Shopify provide integration with Third-party payment providers. I hope you can get third party payment provider.

Otherwise, you can request to shopify to build/integrate new payment method with hosted payment gateway. For this you need to submit [google form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe7aB9HkDQ6z3OgNYanFUUFMofntNlsCmNfwT_pmzfD9Jqi4A/viewform) to shopify team, once they approved then you can integrate third party payment method.Better way you can discuss with your payment provider to build app if more shopify users have same requirements.